# How do I make wait for loop, until selenium wait for the button to be pressed?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in python selenium. So I am asking for the help from you guys.

Here I need help with following lines of code, that how do I make the wait to for loop until the Webdriver wait is over.

in this line of code, For loop start executing next iteration even when the web driver  still waiting for a button to be pressed

```
N = 10

for i in range(0, N):
    fillupform(driver)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_submit")))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't wait for a button to be pressed (clicked)... it's waiting for an element to be clickable. You aren't actually clicking it, if that's what you intended.

Comment: @Deep I have updated my answer is should work!

Comment: @Deep let me know if it worked or if you have any questions...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Just change your wait to:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=1000, poll_frequency=1).until(ec.staleness_of((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_submit")))
```

What I have done is I added `poll_frequency` that it should not check every half a second... see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait).

And I changed the "Expected Conditions" to `staleness_of` instead of `element_to_be_clickable`.

You can read more about wait's [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have tried to rewrite the code, and written" fillupform()" first and then "webdriverwait" but the result is same.

Comment: @Deep Can you show the code for the function `fillupform`?

Comment: def fillupform(driver):
        s1 = ss[0].split(' ')
        l1 = len(s1)
        ip = []
        for i in range(0, l1):
            if i == l1 - 1:
                lname = s1[i]
            elif i == l1 - 2:
                fname = s1[i]
            else:
                ip.append(s1[i])
        ip = "".join(ip)
     driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt_ipaddress").send_keys(ip)
     driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt_firstname").send_keys(fname)
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt_lastname").send_keys(lname)

Comment: I am still missing something... What is `ss`... But still why can't you just put the wait within the function... Where are you looking for the elements!!!

Comment: actually I want webdrive to wait, until the user press "ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_submit" button